# TTL in Mongo DB using C# stop working after expiry index date field is stored as string

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the Time To Live option to set the expiry of items in MONGO DB. Previously it was working because the field `CreatedAt` format used to be `BSON Date Format` but later we needed to convert our whole object into JSON and then back to BSON before saving it to MONGO DB.
After that conversion, `CreatedAt` is stored as string format and the problem starts with TTL.

DB Configuration:

```
 private void InitializeSessionCollection(MongoDbOptions dbOptions)
        {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<Session>(nameof(Session));

        var indexKeysDefinition = Builders<Session>.IndexKeys.Descending(l => l.CreatedAt);
        var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions
        {
            ExpireAfter = dbOptions.SessionTimeout,
            Name = "TimeToLiveIndex"
        };
        var model = new CreateIndexModel<Session>(indexKeysDefinition, indexOptions);

        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        {
            collection.Indexes.CreateOne(model, cancellationToken: cts.Token);
        }
    }
```

Previously DB stored format: (TTL working with it)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "RqcDGqCmokyxipJ+jTi7Sw==",
      "subType": "03"
    }
  },
  "CreatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1659538489113"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently DB stored format:(TTL not working with it)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62ea84638919f5904e6b6bfd"
  },
 "CreatedAt": "2022-08-03T19:17:03.8851421+05:30"
}
```

Using the following generic code to save the object into DB:

```
 public async Task AddDocumentAsync(TDocument document)
        {
            var bsonDocument = SerializeDocument(document);
            await _collection.InsertOneAsync(bsonDocument).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        private BsonDocument SerializeDocument(TDocument document)
        {
            var jsonDocument = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
            return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(jsonDocument);
        }
```

Please help me into resolving this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of help you expect? TTL indices work only of date fields (BSON type 9): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a TTL index, you need a datetime property. For a lot of other reasons, it is preferrable to use datetime properties instead of strings.

You can update the documents in a script with an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "CreatedAt": {
    $type: "string"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "CreatedAt": {
        $toDate: "$CreatedAt"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

You can try the script with this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hE9a8SCyRHt).

When storing data, you can use the .NET `DateTime` directly. MongoDB will store this as a UTC datetime.